# I cannot install python module cv2 on windows 7 with pip

Tags: python, pip, opencv, python-3.8

I can not install Python module cv2 with the command `"pip install cv2"`

OS: Windows 7 64bit

error:

```
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement cv2 <from versions: none >
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2; however, version 20.2.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading
```

Comment: You want to install opencv? pip install opencv-python

Answer (score 2):

Install [OpenCv](https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/#description) instead of `cv2` :

> `pip install opencv-python`

Will work

[OpenCv tutorial](https://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_setup/py_setup_in_windows/py_setup_in_windows.html)